# how to update google play services on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I use eclipse to develop android.

I get this error:

```
    10-28 15:31:02.020: I/Ads(5593): 
Received log message: <Google:HTML> You are using version 8.3 of the Google Play services Ads SDK. 
Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes.
 See xxxx for instructions on how to get the latest version of Google Play services.
```

But I use eclipse. documents says for android studio. My project is very big and now I cant convert it for now from eclipse to adt.

### **UPDATE**

### I use all of these in another project and it is all fine. I can t understand what happened?

thanks in advance

Comment: `Ecplise User` ? WOW

Comment: yes I use eclipse to develop android for some project.

Comment: `My project is very big and now I cant convert it for now from eclipse to adt.` Later on you will be needing to migrate on AS, and It might be too late the moment you realize that it is much *seriously* bigger than the prev size. :)

Comment: what a rude comments, I have android studio projects too ,and in this project I need to use eclipse so My question is this, if you do not the answer Please do not comment

Answer (score 1):

Google is trying his best to force you to use Android Studio. I had similar problem, then I just manually downloaded play services project and added to my project.

Long store short, you can get it from here:
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-ads

this is old, but already configured:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55162356/google-play-services_lib.zip

Comment: thanks for answer, it is what I want but the version is old. Can you share the updated version?

Comment: This is all I have. It is possible to download from Google and then extract it from aar files (that is how I did, but long time ago, can't remember exact steps)

Comment: thanks for answer, I upvote your answer but I need still update version, I try your solution

Comment: check the updated answer. You can also download the updated GPS from github repository given above

Comment: In that link there are 5 deps,  4 is broken